# Fetch rows from database table android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to return the array of rows where the username matches the username in the database table. The JSON result just gives me the last row.

**example table:**

```
james 14 u@aol.com

mah 12 j@aol.com

james 23 ra@yahoo.com

result gives me:
23 ra@yahoo.com
```

but i want both james rows not just the last one.
so both 14 u@aol.com and 23 ra@yahoo.com
 thanks

**My php code:**

```
<?php 
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $con = new mysqli("xx", "xx", "xx", "xx");


    // selects everything 
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    // Store the result to use
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $username, $age, $email);

    // Get results returned and put in array
    $user = array();
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $user[age] = $age;
        $user[email] = $email;
    }

    // Send array back to phone
    print (json_encode($user));

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the array so try something like this

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $user[] = array( 'age'=>$age, 'email'=>$email);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be empty not like [age][email] it should be empty so that array create index.

Answer (score 1):

`user[]` should be a 2 dimensional array.

In your case last element will be there in the array.

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $user[] = array('age'=>$age,'email' =>$email);
    }
```

Hope this helps.